# Adding a workarea to canvas react

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, node-canvas, konvajs-reactjs

I am working with react-konva, which uses node canvas. Now I am trying to create a workarea as can be seen on: https://salgum1114.github.io/react-design-editor/
I have looked at the source-code for that, but it immensely complex. And uses fabric.

Can the same thing can be done using react-konva?